# Delegated rights to Enable/Disable TSQL Jobs (Specific Jobs)

Tags: sql-server

I attempted to write a wrapper for users to be able to enable/disable certain jobs. Trying to avoid the pitfalls of allowing users access to modify everything in a job and avoid code elevation, I wrote this test harness that executes as a certificate based user with a signed stored procedure in msdb.

As I understand, the only requirement should be to allow the user to execute the stored procedure, and the cert user needs SQL operator role in order to run `sp_update_job`. Perhaps I am missing something here but the stored procedure appears to be executing as the caller not as the cert-based user even though it is signed. I think I am missing something completely obvious here.

Below is a test harness:

```
USE [msdb]
GO

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)

EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'TestJob', 
@enabled=1, 
@notify_level_eventlog=0, 
@notify_level_email=2, 
@notify_level_page=2, 
@delete_level=0, 
@category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
@owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.certificates where NAME = 'JobExecTestCert')
BEGIN
    CREATE CERTIFICATE [JobExecTestCert]
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = N'Password1'
    WITH SUBJECT = N'Certificate for executing jobs wrapper'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.server_principals WHERE NAME = 'JobExecTest' AND TYPE = 'C')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER JobExecTest FROM CERTIFICATE JobExecTestCert
    ALTER ROLE SQLAgentOperatorRole ADD MEMBER JobExecTest
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE type = 'R' AND name = 'TestJob_Exec')
BEGIN
    CREATE ROLE TestJob_Exec
END
GO

USE msdb
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_EnableDisableTestJob] @enabled CHAR(1) AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @JobName sysname,
@enabledflag TINYINT,
@jobid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,

SELECT @enabledflag = CASE @enabled
WHEN 'Y' THEN 1
WHEN 'N' THEN 0
ELSE 1
END 

SELECT SYSTEM_USER 'system Login'  
   , USER AS 'Database Login'  
   , NAME AS 'Context'  
   , TYPE  
   , USAGE   
   FROM sys.user_token  



EXEC [sp_update_job] @job_name = 'TestJob', @enabled = @enabledflag 

END
GO


ADD SIGNATURE
TO [dbo].[usp_EnableDisableTestJob]
BY CERTIFICATE [JobExecTestCert]
WITH PASSWORD = 'Password1';

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[usp_EnableDisableTestJob] TO [TestJob_Exec]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'TestUsr')
BEGIN
CREATE LOGIN TestUsr WITH PASSWORD = 'Password1'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'TestUsr')
BEGIN
CREATE USER TestUsr FROM LOGIN TestUsr
ALTER ROLE [TestJob_Exec] ADD MEMBER TestUsr
END


EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'TestUsr';  
GO  
[dbo].[usp_EnableDisableTestJob] 
   @enabled = 'Y'
   GO

SELECT SUSER_NAME()
```

The stored procedure is executing as caller rather than cert based user.

Comment: So what *does* happen when someone tries to execute the procedure?

Comment: Well, that's how it works, you always execute as whoever you execute as, unless you call EXECUTE AS or use EXECUTE as Owner etc. But it shouldn't matter what you execute as since you should have the rights you need to do what you need to do.

Comment: Msg 14262, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_verify_job_identifiers, Line 67 [Batch Start Line 85]
The specified @job_name ('TestJob') does not exist.

Comment: It executes as the signed stored proc because it is signed, that's the point of signing the stored proc for situations like this where you don't want the grant impersonate rights and have to use EXECUTE AS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: your user need to be member of one of the following (ISNULL(IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(N'sysadmin'), 0) = 1)
   OR (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'SQLAgentReaderRole'), 0) = 1)
   OR ( (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'TargetServersRole'), 0) = 1) otherwise it won't see the jobs, see sysjobs_view in msdb

Comment: The harness adds the cert user to the SQLAgentOperator role.

ALTER ROLE SQLAgentOperatorRole ADD MEMBER JobExecTest

Comment: signing is for rights, not for impersonation me thinks, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate

Comment: SQLAgentReaderRole is not SQLAgentOperator. But i don't think cert user is the right user to add, does it work if you add the real user to SQLAgentReaderRole ?

Comment: The signed proc I believe would have to run as the cert based user because that's where the rights are assigned.  Perhaps I am wrong but I have used the exact same approach to avoid having to grant ddl_admin for a user to a fixed DB role circumventing the need for placing a user into the ddl_admin fixed db role. From my perspective that is no different in MSDB from avoid putting a user into the SQLAgentOperator role.

Comment: SQLAgentOperator is a member of SQLAgentReader role by default in every msdb so it shouldnt be that.

Comment: Yeah, but as i wrote, the jobs view checks the rights explicitely, so it's a bit different that just "gain" rights through stuff

Comment: if you only add SQLAgentReaderRole to the normal user, at least there will not be any way of changing jobs

Comment: Here is the answer which someone on another forum answered:

Countersignatures
When executing a signed module, the signatures will be temporarily added to the SQL token, but the signatures are lost if the module executes another module or if the module terminates execution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-signature-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#countersignatures

Answer (score 0):

The issue is countersignatures.

An excerpt from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-signature-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#countersignatures

When executing a signed module, the signatures will be temporarily added to the SQL token, but the **signatures are lost if the module executes another module or if the module terminates execution**. A countersignature is a special form of signature. **By itself, a countersignature doesn't grant any permissions, however, it allows signatures made by the same certificate or asymmetric key to be kept for the duration of the call made to the countersigned object.**

The issue is that the code calls:

```
EXEC [sp_update_job] @job_name = 'TestJob', @enabled = @enabledflag
```

Which is calling another stored procedure.  The answer is to countersign   sp_update_job in msdb.

```
ADD SIGNATURE
TO [dbo].[sp_update_job]
BY CERTIFICATE [JobExecTestCert]
WITH PASSWORD = 'Password1';
```

Once the the msdb update job proc is signed the procedure executes correctly.